# Create external list forms using infopath

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to create external list forms using InfoPath.

I have aready been able to do following in this process:
1. Create External Content Type using sharepoint designer
2. Create External List using sharepoint designer

Now I am trying to modify forms (submit and retrieve forms) using InfoPath. I am following the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554886%28office.14%29.aspx.

But in the design checker task pane I see a warning saying "Could not verify the form template on the specified server". I cannot find anywhere in msdn or google addressing this warning. Inspite of this warning i tried to quick publish the form, and then i get an error saying: "The form template has been published to the server but it can only be opened in the InfoPath Editor because it contains feature that are not compatible with web browsers, to fix this problem, click close and review the errors in the Design Checker task pane"